# Working with arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays

SO I'm working with array's in java, and I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to list of f the locations of the least occurring number in an array with a length of 100, with a range of 0-9. I'm using a second array to count the occurrences, and it all works out until my last piece of code.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Program6
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[] bigArray = new int[100];
    int[] count = new int[10];


    for (int i = 0; i < bigArray.length ;i++ )
        {
            bigArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);    
        }
    for (int i = 0; i < bigArray.length ;i++ )  
        {   
            System.out.println(bigArray[i] + " ");  
        }
    for(int i = 0; i < bigArray.length; i++)
        {
            count[bigArray[i]]++;
        }



    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < count.length ;i++, j++)  
            System.out.println("count for " + j +" is: " + count[i] + " "); 

    int min = count[0];
    int indexOfMin = 0;

    for ( int i =1; i < count.length; i++)
        {   if (count[i] < min ) 
                {
                    min = count[i];
                    indexOfMin = i; 
                }
        }

    System.out.println("\nThe number " + indexOfMin + " only appears " + min  + " times in the array.");
    System.out.println("It appears in the large array at: ");

    \\this guy right here 
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < bigArray.length; i++)
        {   if (bigArray[i] == min ) 
                {
                    System.out.println("bigArray["+ i + "]");

                }
        }

}
```

}

It should just list off the array locations. But it returns way more than just the locations of the lowest occurring integer, even though the qualifier is using the variable *min*.

What gives? What am i missing?

There is no input, the output that returns is

```
8 
 ..
4 
count for 0 is: 18 
count for 1 is: 6 
count for 2 is: 9 
count for 3 is: 9 
count for 4 is: 16 
count for 5 is: 4 
count for 6 is: 12 
count for 7 is: 8 
count for 8 is: 7 
count for 9 is: 11     

The number 5 only appears 4 times in the array.
It appears in the large array at: 
bigArray[3]
bigArray[6]
bigArray[10]
bigArray[23]
bigArray[25]
bigArray[39]
bigArray[44]
bigArray[48]
bigArray[49]
bigArray[50]
bigArray[51]
bigArray[57]
bigArray[58]
bigArray[67]
bigArray[84]
bigArray[99]
```

which is perfect, except for the bigArray[] list out. It should only show where the index when the array is equal to the least occurring number.

Comment: Please show the input, the actual output and the expected output.

Comment: I have found an indentation style I dislike even more than just braces-on-newline!

Comment: What if the minimum is, say, 5, and two (or more) numbers occur 5 times.

Comment: Oddly enough, that's just what happens when i copy text out of my text-editor, i don't really indent like this!

Comment: I'm not worried about multiple least occurring values right now. But what I think I just make a for clause that could handle multiple values, and then modify my output to have two variables, or use an if clause to determine which way it should go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing against the count of the number. use the number instead. Update

```
//this guy right here 
for ( int i = 0 ; i < bigArray.length; i++)
    {   if (bigArray[i] == min ) 
            {
                System.out.println("bigArray["+ i + "]");

            }
    }
```

to use `indexOfMin` as

```
`//this guy right here 
for ( int i = 0 ; i < bigArray.length; i++)
    {   if (bigArray[i] == indexOfMin) 
            {
                System.out.println("bigArray["+ i + "]");

            }
    }
```